# When should I use "hey there" or "hi there"?

Tags: phrases

I know it's a way of greeting someone, but I am not so sure when should I be using it, and how they differ from "hey" or "hi".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a personal preference.  Both "hi there" and "hi" are informal greetings that can be used interchangeably.  That being said, I rarely (if ever) hear someone use "hey there" or "hi there".  I would say that those forms have fallen into relative disuse.

If you happen to be a [Mouseketeer](http://www.hitslyrics.com/d/disney-lyrics-6472/mickeymousemarch-lyrics-511846.html) in the 1950's, you may not have a choice in the matter.

Comment: +1: For the Mouseketeer reference, but you left out "Ho there"! Don't leave me hangin', bro!

Comment: I still hear these expansions a lot, and see them a good deal more in emails/IM, maybe it has not died out everywhere.

Comment: @Robusto I also can't help but think of 'Bob' from "That 70's Show".

Comment: Going to take a risk here by adding that my own **informal** observation tells me that females prefer to use "Hey .." compared to "Hi .." Not sure why. Anyone can confirm or disprove this observation?

Comment: Hey there! :D I use "Hey there!" almost everyday when meeting someone.